# Filter id in an array of object based on an array of id's

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

I am trying to display Heart icon for the items that are added to the Wishlist. I am using local storage to save the items that are wishlisted. I have an array of id's such as `wishlistIds = [123,425,212,512,516]`. So I want to check if the id's in that array matches with the array of objects (which are the products). Product array of objects looks like this;

```
 items = [{id:123, productName:"Cheese", price: 15.99}, {id:599, productName: "Honey", price:21.99}]
```

I have been trying to use Array.filter method to achieve what I want, but couldn't make it work;

```
wishlistIds.filter(w => w.id === items.id)
```

The above code returns me all the ids inside the wishlistIds without filtering the id's inside the the items. What is the correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: `items` is an array. It has no `id` property.

Comment: Do you want to get the intersection of both lists? I.e. the ids of all products that are wishlisted *and* in the current set of items?

Comment: @RubenHelsloot correct

Comment: probably one solution is `wishlistIds.filter(w =>items.find(item => w.id === item.id) > 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of item IDs and use that to filter the wishlist array

```js
const wishlistIds = [123,425,212,512,516]
const items = [{id:123, productName:"Cheese", price: 15.99}, {id:599, productName: "Honey", price:21.99}]

const itemIds = new Set(items.map(({ id }) => id))

const filteredWishlist = wishlistIds.filter(id => itemIds.has(id))

console.log(filteredWishlist)
```

I'm using a `Set` here as `Set.prototype.has()` is *O(1)* time complexity as opposed to `Array.prototype.includes()` which is *O(n)*.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#performance

Answer (score 2):

First filter the list, then map it to get just the ID

```js
let wishlistIds = [123,425,212,512,516]
let items = [{id:123, productName:"Cheese", price: 15.99}, {id:599, productName: "Honey", price:21.99}]
let hearts = items.filter(w => wishlistIds.includes(w.id)).map(w => w.id)
console.log(hearts)
```